# how to include external svn repository in phabricator?

Tags: svn, version-control, phabricator

I've been running subversion for a few years now and have just installed phabricator for some management and code review tools. However, I can't find a way to include my exisiting subversion repositories located on the local server into phabricator.

any ideas how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently (it took far too many clicks to discover this) the version control interface portion of Phabricator is called "Diffusion" and the instructions for installing/configuring it are [here](http://www.phabricator.com/docs/phabricator/article/Diffusion_User_Guide.html)

However, that page only provides instructions for creating a *new* repository within the tool, not linking to an existing one.